# Do I need a physical print-out of weight & balance calculations onboard

Tags: safety, regulations, easa-regulations

Our flight school taught us to print out some documents relevant to flight preparation and take them onboard the aircraft: This usually included
`weight & balance` as well as `takeoff/landing performance` at dep./dest. airports.

I believe this was established as best practice, but not mandated by SERA.
Am I required to have paper versions of certain documents onboard the aircraft at all times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Weight & Balance:

[SERA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardised_European_Rules_of_the_Air) Annex VII (Part-NCO)
*Non-commercial operations with other than complex-motor-powered aircraft*
Subpart C: AIRCRAFT PERFORMANCE AND OPERATING LIMITATIONS
[NCO.POL.100 Operating limitations – all aircraft](https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/easy-access-rules/online-publications/easy-access-rules-air-operations?page=62#_Toc8627156)

> During any phase of operation, the loading, the mass and, the centre of gravity (CG) position of the aircraft shall comply with any limitation specified in the AFM or equivalent document.

and

[SERA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardised_European_Rules_of_the_Air) Annex VII (Part-NCO)
*Non-commercial operations with other than complex-motor-powered aircraft*
Subpart A: GENERAL REQUIREMENTS
[NCO.GEN.135 Documents, manuals and information to be carried](https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/easy-access-rules/online-publications/easy-access-rules-air-operations?page=60#_Toc8627001)

> The following documents, manuals and information shall be carried
> on each flight as originals or copies unless otherwise specified:
>
> (1) the AFM, or equivalent document(s);
> (2) the original certificate of registration;
> (3) the original certificate of airworthiness (CofA);
> (4) the noise certificate, if applicable;
> (5) the list of specific approvals, if applicable;
> (6) the aircraft radio licence, if applicable;
> (7) the third party liability insurance certificate(s);
> (8) the journey log, or equivalent, for the aircraft;
> (9) details of the filed ATS flight plan, if applicable;
> (10) current and suitable aeronautical charts for the route area of
> the proposed flight and all routes along which it is reasonable to
> expect that the flight may be diverted;
> (11) procedures and visual signals information for use by intercepting
> and intercepted aircraft;
> (12) the MEL or CDL, if applicable; and
> (13) any other documentation that may be pertinent to the flight or is
> required by the States concerned with the flight.

So, per SERA, the weight & balance sheet does not need to be carried on-board. Pre-flight weight & balance calculations must show that the airplane remains within loading limits from takeoff weight to landing weight.

2. Paper & Digital Versions:

Edit:

*GM1 NCO.GEN.135 Documents, manuals and information to be carried* [now reads](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/document-library/easy-access-rules/online-publications/easy-access-rules-air-operations?page=60#_Toc8627001):

> The documents, manuals and information may be available in a form other than on printed paper. An electronic storage medium is acceptable if accessibility, usability and reliability can be assured.